# matlab neural network training batch size

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm trying to train a neural network using different batch sizes, but I'm not sure how to merge the resultant networks together.

Here's the code I wrote to train a network with batch size as a parameter.

```
%% Train the Network using batches
batch_size = 50;

total_size = size(inputs,2);
batch_num = ceil(total_size / batch_size);

for i = 1:batch_num
    start_index = i + batch_size * (i - 1);
    end_index = batch_size + batch_size * (i - 1);

    if i == batch_num
        end_index = total_size;
    end

    [net,tr] = train(net,inputs(:,start_index:end_index), targets(:,start_index:end_index));
end
```

this is the structure of net and tr

tr =

```
    trainFcn: 'traingdm'
  trainParam: [1x1 nnetParam]
  performFcn: 'mse'
performParam: [1x1 nnetParam]
    derivFcn: 'defaultderiv'
   divideFcn: 'dividerand'
  divideMode: 'sample'
 divideParam: [1x1 nnetParam]
    trainInd: [1x538 double]
      valInd: [1x115 double]
        ...
```

net =

```
Neural Network

          name: 'Pattern Recognition Neural Network'
    efficiency: .cacheDelayedInputs, .flattenTime,
                .memoryReduction
      userdata: (your custom info)

dimensions:

     numInputs: 1
     numLayers: 4
    numOutputs: 1
numInputDelays: 0
numLayerDelays: 0
 numFeedbackDelays: 0
 numWeightElements: 845
    sampleTime: 1

connections:

   biasConnect: [1; 1; 1; 1]
  inputConnect: [1; 0; 0; 0]
  layerConnect: [4x4 boolean]
 outputConnect: [0 0 0 1]

subobjects:

        inputs: {1x1 cell array of 1 input}
        layers: {4x1 cell array of 4 layers}
       outputs: {1x4 cell array of 1 output}
        biases: {4x1 cell array of 4 biases}
  inputWeights: {4x1 cell array of 1 weight}
  layerWeights: {4x4 cell array of 3 weights}
    ...
```

how would I get the resultant `net` variable to hold the resultant neural net after all the batches have completed?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are overriding the variables `net` and `tr`. Just use a cell array:

Declare it at the beginning using:

```
 net = {};
 tr = {};
```

And change the relevant line to:

```
 [net{end+1},tr{end+1}] = ...
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems that net and tr are more complicated

Comment: It should work anyhow, since you can make cell arrays of any type of object, no matter how complex it is. Does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately no. net is a 1x1 network. This is the error I get: ??? Comma separated list expansion has cell
syntax for an array that
is not a cell.

Error in ==> classification at 122
     [net{end+1},tr{end+1}] =
     train(net,inputs(:,start_index:end_index),
     targets(:,start_index:end_index));

Comment: still doesn't work. I think I can just keep on using net it won't overwrite it since I also use it as an input parameter. For tr I think I'll just get it the first iteration and stop generating it for the next ones. Thanks for your help